# Поиск по словам в интернете и получить первый сайт и данные этой страницы

Tags: html, html5, парсер, google-search

Хотелось бы узнать есть ли фреймворк, позволяющий искать слово в интернете, например через гугл, и получить первый сайт в списке в виде докумнета и извлечь из него определение этого слова, или даже абзац. И все это должно происходить в сервере. Возможно ли так сделать?
Спасибо заранее!

Answer (score 1):

это называется парсинг(есть много библиотек на эту тему). да возможно. насчет сайта в виде документа ... я так и не понял, по точнее напиши. Запросы через гугл , раньше можно было, они предоставляли такие услуги(вроде дажже библиотеки , или API, не помню) , а сейчас не знаю.

Comment: а да у тебя тег парсинг, не смотрел

Comment: по точнее опиши суть не понятно

Comment: Хай! Спасибо за ответ. По точнее получается так: как пример приведу: допустим мне нужно значение одного слова, при запросе через ключевое слово или словосочетание Гугл выдает много сайтов. И в списке всех сайтов, получить самый первый сайт (допустим Википедиа), отфильтровать не нужное, а оставить только разъеснение этого слова, допустим один абзац. И это все получить в форме не знаю, например json-документа (под документом я скорее это и имел ввиду, сорри что сразу не уточнил), чтобы полученный документ мне дальше обработать.

Comment: Кроме json-документа ничего на ум не приходит

Comment: там по тегам и ссылкам в сайте ищешь(парсишь, F12 для разработчиков), если сайты одинаковые то и ссылки на абзац одинаковые. берешь текст и пихаешь его в массив(лучше наверное в массив) , который потом в файл json

Comment: mongoDb (как база данных)